# Control events trigger on other forms than my intended formC#

Tags: c#, winforms

I got a question about creating new forms in C#.
I want to create multiple forms (MainPanel) as shown in the code below. This creates a new form and displays it.

```cs
        private void Panel_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            Form mp = new MainPanel();
            mp.Show();
        }
```

In the MainPanel form I have some events and controls set up. One of the is an exit button, if you press it, it closes the form

```cs
    public partial class MainPanel : Form
    {
        private static MainPanel mainPanel;
        public MainPanel()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            mainPanel = this;

            Panel panel = new Panel();
            panel.Name = "ExitButton";
            panel.BackColor = ExitButtonColor;
            panel.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.None;
            panel.BackColor = Color.Transparent;
            panel.Width = 30;
            panel.Height = 30;

            panel.MouseClick += PanelExit_MouseClick;
            this.Controls.Add(panel);
        }

        private static void PanelExit_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            mainPanel.Close();
        }
}
```

When I call for `Form mp = new MainPanel();` and `.Show()` it, it works like intended and opens. The exit button works too.
How ever, when I open a second one by creating a new `new MainPanel();` and then `.Show();` it. Then the exit button does not really work.

That means I have 2 open MainPanel forms, both have their own exit button. If I click on the first form exit button, clicking it will close the second form.
Clicking on the exit button on the second form will also close the second form. In other words, all the events on my first form are being fired and executed on my second form.

Any idea why that happens or how to avoid it?

Comment: It is not obvious why you used `static`, but that's what happens when you do.  As-is, you must not allow a second instance to be created.

Comment: You state that… _”That means I have 2 open MainPanel forms, both have their own exit button. If I click on the first form exit button, clicking it will close the second form.”_ … “Where” is the code for this `ButtonClick` event on the `MainPanel` forms? … the posted code shows a `MouseClick` event when a `Panel` is clicked on. So it is unclear where the code for the “Exit” Button click event is and can only guess what it is doing.

Comment: Hans is right, remove your "static" keywords and it works.

Comment: In addition, after further review, in the `MainPanel` `Form`, the code is “adding” a `Panel` `panel` to the form. It is a small panel that basically the user cannot see …`panel.BackColor = Color.Transparent;` … however… if the user clicks on this “invisible” panel… the form closes … ? … My sympathies to your users.

Comment: @JohnG In my original code the panel is a circle using brush to draw. Where the drawn circle has a red color and the rest of the panel is invisible. I just did not want to post unnecessary code in this question. I guess i forgot to change the color too.

Speaking of the panel, the panel is therefor a 'button' so the click event on the panel is what I mean by button. Hence the panel name. Apologies for the lack of code outside the question.

Comment: Well, as already noted in the comments… creating a `static` `MainPanel` `mainPanel` may cause a problem, however, creating a `MainPanel` object IN the `MainPanel` object is “odd,” confusing and appears to be totally unnecessary. Drop the `mainPanel` variable altogether and simply call `this.Close();` in the `PanelExit_MouseClick` event. This should also solve your current issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It is not obvious why you used static, but that's what happens when you do. As-is, you must not allow a second instance to be created

As Hans comment under my post, I kept all my variables and methods static, keeping it the same for all created forms. Removing the static from the methods and variables did the job.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Side note, you don't need "mainPanel" at all though. Why store a reference to `this`? Just use it directly...

Change:

```
private static void PanelExit_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    mainPanel.Close();
}
```

To:

```
private void PanelExit_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    this.Close();
}
```

Removing static from the method signature as well.